# java objects, and frame not working

Tags: java, jframe, actionlistener

I am trying to create a simple program that changes the text in some text boxes when a specific radio button is pressed. This is my first time with Java so I'm not sure what I've missed out. Here is my code.

```
public abstract class DoctorOption extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JTextField myTxt = new JTextField(30);
    JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
    JRadioButton mywellRB = new JRadioButton("click here if you are well", true);
    JRadioButton myunwellRB = new JRadioButton("click here if you are unwell", false);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DoctorOption() {
        };
    }

    public DoctorOption() {
        setSize(400, 120);
        setTitle("Doctor Option");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        add(myTxt);
        add(mywellRB);
        add(myunwellRB);
        add(submit);
        submit.addActionListener(this);
        myunwellRB.addActionListener(this);
        mywellRB.addActionListener(this);
        setVisible(true);

        ButtonGroup buttons = new ButtonGroup();
        buttons.add(mywellRB);
        buttons.add(myunwellRB);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == mywellRB) {
            myTxt.setText("in the pink! ");
            myTxt.setBackground(Color.pink);
        }
    }
}
```

Please could you help me understand what I have done wrong, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem I see, is that you are not using any layout which means it will default to BorderLayout. BorderLayout defaults to put everything in BorderLayout.CENTER, so you will see one thing take up the entire window. Put this line of code in your constructor:

```
  setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

[For more info on Layouts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are implementing `ActionListener` interface so you need to implement `actionPerformed` method.Change your main method like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new DoctorOption(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // put relevant code here

        }};
}
```